# s3 no such key, The specified key does not exist. previewing document from url

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, iframe, amazon-s3

Im using paperclip, s3. I have uploaded a word document and now i want to be able to preview it from the database.  I'm using an iframe.

[image]

```html
<iframe src="<%= agreement.document.url(:small) %>" frameborder="0" width="400" height="400" allowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true"> </iframe>
```

all in all i get this error. how can i preview the word document or pdf??

**UPDATED:**
I have got the pdf to show however the word document is not wanting to show. The word document shows up blank the pdf shows, and the word document instead ask if i want to download the file.

So instead of showing the word document it asks for me to download it.

This is what i changed:

```html
<iframe src="<%= agreement.document.url() %>" frameborder="0" width="400" height="400" allowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true"> </iframe>
```

So now all in all how do i let the word document work? it's a docx

Answer (score 0):

Either the bucket name is not correct, or the file does not exist on the bucket.

Also make sure permissions on the file are public, if you want it to be accessible by everyone.

Comment: when i only use `agreement.document` or `agreement.document.url` for the `src`, it asks me to download the file, so it means i have permission and its pointing to the right file. iv tried including my domain name `www.domain.com/<%= agreement.document.url(:small) %>` with that i get a different error about how the |get| path doesnt exist.

Comment: Can you check if you can view the document by hardcoding the link? If it works, then something is wrong with your code and not s3.

Comment: i updated my question as i got the pdf to work but not the word document ^^

Comment: I don't think all browsers will be able to preview word documents out of the box. You should show a preview using pdf and provide a download link for word doc.